# Why does python protobuf json_format.Parse throw a TypeError?

Tags: python, protocol-buffers

I am experimenting with protobuf serialization to JSON. I made a simple proto file with the following messages:

```
syntax = "proto3";
message Bool {
    bool data = 1;
}

message BoolArray {
    repeated Bool bools = 1;
}
```

I then run some basic code to build the message, push to Json, then read it back in:

```
pb_bool_array = pb_bool.BoolArray()
b = pb_bool_array.bools.add()
b.data = True
bools_as_json = MessageToJson( pb_bool_array )

Parse(bools_as_json, proto.bool_pb2.BoolArray )
```

but the Parse function throws a `TypeError` with the following message:

> google.protobuf.json_format.ParseError: Failed to parse bools field:
>   unbound method ClearField() must be called with BoolArray instance as
>   first argument (got str instance instead).

I traced the Parse function and this error fires off on line 519 in Google's `json_format` code. Why would this TypeError occur? Am I missing something in my proto spec and/or abusing the python API?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

After further analysis of the `json_format.Parse()` function, I realized that I was abusing the [API](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/python/).

```
Parse(bools_as_json, proto.bool_pb2.BoolArray )
```

should *really* be:

```
Parse(bools_as_json, proto.bool_pb2.BoolArray() )
```

The API expects a message *instance* to fill, not the type of message. Everything works as expected.