# Parse() missing 1 required positional argument: 'message

Tags: json, protocol-buffers

I am tring to convert JSON to the protocol buffer in django rest framework.
But getting above error:

```
class Proto(APIView):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            data={
                "name": "Ashutosh",
                "age":  "26",
                "city": "gurgaon",
                "phone_number": "9717"
            }
            data = str(data)
            parsed_data = json.dumps(ast.literal_eval(data))
            #message = Parse(json.dumps(parsed_data))
            a = google.protobuf.json_format.Parse(parsed_data)
            return Response({'status':'SUCCESS','data':"pending...."},status=200)
        except Exception as e:
            return Response({'status':'ERROR','message':str(e)})
```

Some one please tell me what i am missing

Comment: check this list if it might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51559778/why-does-python-protobuf-json-format-parse-throw-a-typeerror

Comment: buddy that is proto to json but my concern is  json to prot

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide `Parse(Dict)` with the message to parse into.

See [Parse](https://googleapis.dev/python/protobuf/latest/google/protobuf/json_format.html#google.protobuf.json_format.Parse)

```
data={
   "name": "Ashutosh",
   "age":  "26",
   "city": "gurgaon",
   "phone_number": "9717"
}

# Whatever these values are in your code
message = your_pb2.YourMessage()

a = google.protobuf.json_format.Parse(json.dumps(data), message)
```

Or, directly from a dict:

```
a = google.protobuf.json_format.ParseDict(data, message)
```

Comment: i do not have your_pb2.YourMessage()

Comment: this is the issue,i have only json response

Comment: can you tell me how to get message in this api

Comment: The only reason to use `Parse(Dict)` is to create a protobuf message. I used `your_pb2.YourMessage()` as an example of the format you should expect to use. You mention "protocol buffer in the Django REST framework", so you should use whatever message that provides.